# Remote Desktop Session to Windows server from an iPad

Tags: remote-desktop, ipad

Is it possible to (ie is there an app) that allows you to use remote desktop connections to windows 2003 and windows 2008 servers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many options in the App Store, but not all detail which versions of Windows they support. 
[Desktop Connect](http://antecea.com/products/desktop-connect.html) specifically states support for Windows 2003 and 2008 Server.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, try [WinAdmin](http://itunes.apple.com/au/app/winadmin-ipad-edition/id364898965?mt=8).